# AngularJS: Passing parameters

Tags: angularjs

This is my angular code.

```
dataService.addFrameInventory($routeParams.id, $scope.newFrameInventory)
 .then(function() {
   },
   function() {
   });
```

This is my factory code

```
    var _addFrameInventory = function (frameId, newFrameInventory) {

    var params = { frameId: frameId, newFrameInventory: newFrameInventory };
    $http.post("../api/v1/FrameInventory/post", params)
       .then(function (result) {
              //success
       },
           function () {
               //error
           });
     };
```

This is my api controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]FrameInventory frameInventory)
{
    _repository.Save(frameInventory);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, frameInventory);
}
```

This is my model

```
public class FrameInventory
{
   Id {get; set;} //Identity column
   FrameId {get; set;}
   Supplier {get; set;}
   StockUnits {get; set;}
   StockReceivedDate {get; set;}
   StockUnits {get; set;}
   ...
}
```

This is what I see in chrome. I've all values in `params`.
[image]
But into the 'Post' method I could only retrieve FrameId correctly and the rest are being null. I'm sure that something is wrong with parameter passing itself. Because I've done unit testing, nothing wrong with the functionality of the method inside the `Post`. But I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: what data do you see in network tab of chrome ?? .Moreever could you share the model structure along with complete real code

Comment: What does `FrameInventory` look like?

Comment: can you show more code?  I can't understand what you're doing

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal I'm getting a 500 server error & see my edit.

Comment: If you're getting a server error, it's a problem on the server. We can't tell what your backend is doing but most likely an error there causing an invalid response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are probably posting the wrong type of object.

You post is expecting to see a `FrameInventory` object, containing `FrameId` and a bunch of other things. It looks like you are handing it `params` containing the object

```
{ frameId: frameId, newFrameInventory: newFrameInventory }
```

Going solely by your variable names, I expect

```
$http.post("../api/v1/FrameInventory/post", params)
```

should read

```
$http.post("../api/v1/FrameInventory/post", newFrameInventory)
```

so long as `newFrameInventory` has the structure you have defined for `FrameInventory`.

Comment: I think you are right.  However, I think if this was the only issue, WebAPI would throw back a 400, not a 500.

Comment: True. What I'm expecting from apps I've written is that all of the properties in `FrameInventory` come out as `null` (including `FrameID` as it would be in the wrong case) and WebAPI takes that as a correct model. Then somewhere in the POST method, we get a null reference exception or other exception based on the model not being what we expect... Obviously without the error or anything else in the tickets it's hard to say for sure though.

Comment: @Andyrooger Please see my edit. I added a image of what `params` contains.

Comment: Yep. Seeing that, you should almost definitely be posting `newInventoryFrame` rather than `params`. If you mean to add `frameId` then you can use `angular.extend(newFrameInventory, {frameId: frameId})`. You may also want to make sure that the case for properties in the client and server models match. I'm not sure if either are case-sensitive.